# How to customize ionic 4 sidemenu?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

im having troubles trying to customize the sidemenu which ionic generates automatically.

The sidemenu is located at "app.component.html" and it looks like it follows:

```
 <ion-app>


    <ion-menu contentId="content1" side="start" >
      <ion-header >
        <ion-toolbar >
          <ion-avatar>
            <img [src]="image">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>



      <ion-content >
        <ion-list >
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages" >
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]" (click)="dembow(p)" >
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="content1" main ></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-app>
```

i've tried to use the attribute "style:background-color:#000000" etc to change the style and it works if i put it on every element , but i would like to know if there is some easier and efficient way to customize the sidemenu.

Thank you team!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is in ionic '<*ion-content*>', '<*ion-list*>' is directives. You can manipulate these directive's template design using css.

for Eg.

In HTML-

```
<div class="side-nav-menu"> <!--wrap side menu in div tag and give class to it-->
<ion-content >
    <ion-list >
       <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages" >
          <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]" (click)="dembow(p)" >
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                 {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</div>
```

In Your Application's Global css file which is app.scss

```
.side-nav-menu{
    //add style if you want any...for eg border, shadow.etc
}
.side-nav-menu .ion-item{
    //style for ion-item    
}
```

NOTE:- Remember the directives(attributes) name is also the class name of the same directive. for eg. if the directive name is ion-item and you want to add custom css to this directive than you have to add css using .ion-item class in global scss file

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ion-content class="abc">

      </ion-content>
```

use content class to change background this way

```
  .abc {

    --background: var(--ion-background-color,linear-gradient(to  left,#E67D22, #1C4577)) !important;

}
```

or use only color instead of gradient

```
   .abc {

    --background: var(--ion-background-color,red) !important;

}
```